# sed or perl pattern match and then multiple actions

Tags: sed, match

I want to search for a *variable* numeric value at the end of a line, once found, do two things:

- append something to the end of that line (for example, an html tag)
- move down as many line as that numeric value and append a line there as well (for example, close the preceding html tag).

Any quick pointers please? Attached is a screenshot of my sample data and desired changes. Note in some cases, if there is no member, there won't be any numeric value at the end of the line. 
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDbSX.jpg)

Comment: `sed` is not the tool for this job.  You probably could do it with `awk`, but I'd be inclined to reach for `perl`, myself.  It's the "move down as many line as that numeric value" that presents a problem for `sed`.  I'm not positive that `sed` *can't* do it, but if it can, the program to accomplish it would not be pretty.

Comment: Show some sample input and output

Comment: @glennjackman, was going to post an example data, but I guess I need to figure out how to post it properly formatted...

Comment: while editing your question, click the question mark icon a the top-right of the textarea: that's the markdown editing help

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Thanks. Yes, I am ok with perl if sed is not the right tool...

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in well structure. It is totally fine to use `sed`.
You need to identify the headers, then operate on them.

### input

```
header 1
    item 1.1
    item 1.2
    item 1.3
header 2
    item 2.1
    item 2.2
    item 2.3
header 3
    item 3.1
    item 3.2
    item 3.3
```

### command

```
sed -r '/^\S/{s@$@<wrap>@; 1!s@^@</wrap>\n@}; $s@$@</wrap>@' input
```

### output

```
header 1<wrap>
    item 1.1
    item 1.2
    item 1.3
</wrap>
header 2<wrap>
    item 2.1
    item 2.2
    item 2.3
</wrap>
header 3<wrap>
    item 3.1
    item 3.2
    item 3.3
</wrap>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess I'll settle with this one liner for now (see my sample data in the question):

```
perl -pe '/\((\d+) members?\)/ && do {$close = $.+$1; s/$/OPEN_TAG/;}; $.==$close && do {s/$/CLOSE_TAG/};' input-file
```